# Where to put tfm and gf files

Tags: fonts, texmf

I am working on custom logo with MetaFont. I build logo.tfm and logo.600gf files but TeX or DviView ignore these.

They try to build the font on the fly failing. What can I Do?

Comment: This is tex live 2015 on windows. I installed all I could.

Comment: What is a `.600gf` file exactly? Usually, you'd have a `.mf` source and then generated files with extensions such as `.600pk`. That's what I've used when including a logo of this kind. (Somebody else turned the logo into the MetaFont so maybe a `.600gf` is an interim file rather than what actually gets used in typesetting?)

Comment: More specifically: I have `<logo>.mf` and `<logo>.600pk`. The font defines a capital `C` at `60pt`. Then the template file sets up `\font\uc=<logo>60`. Obviously, this is a TeX configuration, even though it is in a LaTeX document. I guess that's not ideal but since it is only for a single character used as a logo, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: I have mf for meta font, it reads MyLogo.mf and produces MyLogo.600gf file (and MyLogo.tfm), per mf documentation. I found gftopk executable. I do not use LaTex. Is there a place to put MyLogo.mf file so it could be autogenerated?

Comment: I need to copy the MyLogo.tfm file to texmf-local\fonts\tfm\local run gftopk MyLogo.600gf to make MyLogo.600pk and copy the .600pk to C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\pk\local. Tfm makes TeX happy and pk makes DviOut happy.

Comment: @cfr `GF` is the original output format of Metafont 2; `PK` is only a slightly more compact version.  The extension actually stands for "packed".  Not sure what the OP used to produce these though, since any process invoking  Metafont in a recent distribution will call `gftopk` immediately.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer Thanks. I didn't know that. So `MF` -> `GF` -> `PK`? I wasn't aware that there even was an intermediate step. (I knew that `PK` stood for 'pack'.)

Comment: I am able to read and parse .gf files in code that initiated my question.